# How to make headers uppercase without breaking references in latex?

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I am trying to make section headers uppercase. I tried different packages (`titlesec` and `sectsty`) but always get broken references.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\makeatletter

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}%
        {\uppercase}%
        {\thesection.\enskip}%
        {0pt}%
        {}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        x\label{eq:x}
    \end{equation}
    \section{\ref{eq:x}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no problem if you correctly use `\MakeUppercase` instead of `\uppercase`. Note also the placement.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {}
  {\thesection.\enskip}
  {0pt}
  {\MakeUppercase}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
x\label{eq:x}
\end{equation}

\section{A reference to \ref{eq:x}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

When `babel` is used, this may or may not work, depending on the definition of `\sectionmark`. However, loading `textcase` and using `\MakeTextUppercase` should fix the issue.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{textcase}

\titleformat{\section}
  {}
  {\thesection.\enskip}
  {0pt}
  {\MakeTextUppercase}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
x\label{eq:x}
\end{equation}

\section{A reference to \ref{eq:x}}

\end{document}
```

If you also want to applying formatting to the title, here's a workaround:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{textcase}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\sref}[1]{%
  \lowercase{\ref{#1}}
}

\titleformat{\section}
  {}
  {\thesection.\enskip}
  {0pt}
  {\MakeTextUppercase}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
x\label{eq:x}
\end{equation}

\section{A reference to \emph{\sref{eq:x}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This seems to work. However, it does not work on my document. I think I have narrowed down the problem my use of `\usepackage{babel}` and `\documentclass[english]{article}`. I just can't get it to work. The references always break. Is that a bug?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, with `babel` it doesn't work. I'll add a workaround for this.

Comment: Great! Thanks. That works. However, I ran into yet another problem. If the reference in the header is inside `\emph{}`, then it still breaks. So many riddles...

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, but what's the purpose of having the reference in `\emph`?

Comment: The reference is part of a term that I want to _highlight_ from the other text in the header. For example, "The objection to _1 and 2 implies 3_". This is less ambiguous than "The objection to 1 and 2 implies 3" which could be read as "(The objection to 1) and (2 implies 3)".

Comment: @Daniel I added a workaround, but it requires that labels only have lowercase letters.

Comment: Great, thanks. It is surprisingly to me how complicated it gets...