# Issue with acro and fancyhdr package in xelatex - Using acronyms in section titles

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, acro

### Intro

Recently, I was plagued by an issue with the `acro` package, while writing my thesis with `xelatex`.

My document uses the `fancyhdr` package, where I set the section title to appear at footer. The section title letters appear in upper case.

### The issue

I like to use acronyms when I can. So, I decided to use an acronym request in a section title, such as this:

```
\section{Moving Forward to Distributed \ac{sdn} Management}
```

But for some reason, the engine thought it was funny to forcelly upper case all the text in the section title, transforming an `\ac{sdn}` into an `\ac{SDN}`.

Then, this happened at the footer of the document:
[image: weird footer]

Because of this, I was plagued with a phantom acronym appearing two times at the auxiliary file:

```
\acro@used@once {SDN}{78}{78}{89}
\acro@used@twice {SDN}{79}{79}{90}
```

while these phantom acronym requests appeared at the document building log. 
No acronym requests existed at the specified lines:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! acro error: "undefined"
! 
! You've requested acronym `SDN' on line 499 but you apparently haven't
! defined it, yet!
! Maybe you've misspelled `SDN'?
! 
! See the acro documentation for further information.
! 
! Type <return> to continue.
!...............................................  

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! acro error: "undefined"
! 
! You've requested acronym `SDN' on line 514 but you apparently haven't
! defined it, yet!
! Maybe you've misspelled `SDN'?
! 
! See the acro documentation for further information.
! 
! Type <return> to continue.
!...............................................
```

Comment: By the way, if you would like better solutions, consider the following message: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. The easier it is to copy and test your code, the more likely your question will be answered and can help others in a similar situation. ;)

Comment: ok, look at this: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49221461#49221461

Comment: @thymaro The solution I found is sufficient for me. Thank you for your interest in helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The solution

It seems that the combination of using the `acro` package with the `fancyhdr` package while putting the section title at the footer, has proven to be buggy.
Because of this, I removed the `\ac{sdn}` request from the title, which solved the issue of the phantom `\ac{SDN}` request.

Now, the footer of the document is correct and the phantom acronym requests have disapeared.
[image]

Comment: So, what did you replace it with? Plain text? That's just how I do it, but I am not really happy with it. I consider it a work-around with pitfalls, not a solution...

Comment: Yes, I did just replace it with plain text. What you say is true. This is more of a work-around, but the intention of this post was to provide some light on this strange behaviour when mixing `acro` and `fancyhdr`, since it haunted me for some time and the symptoms were clearly misguiding me.

Comment: Fair point. In that way, one can consider it a solution. Well, I hope it will be helping someone looking for a way of using acronyms and initialisms in titling and headers and footers.

Comment: I'm not sure this really answers the question, just saying don't do the problematic code is not an answer to how to solve the problem. This is a faq and not really related to acro, you would see the same with `\ref` or `\cite` see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252134/how-to-make-headers-uppercase-without-breaking-references-in-latex

Comment: According to the link you provided, this may very well be an issue with `fancyhdr`, since it is the package which defines the header and footer format.
I will try to investigate this issue a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

This is not necessarily bound to `fancyhdr`. The same happens with a simple `\pagestyle{headings}` in the article class.

The problem is that `\sectionmark` does `\MakeUppercase` on the heading and – since `\ac`  and friends are protected commands – changes `\ac{sdn}` into `\ac{SDN}` which then leads to the error message.

- One obvious “solution” is to define the acronym with an uppercase ID instead:

  ```
   \DeclareAcronym{SDN}{...}
  ```

However, this might be a tedious work to change, depending on the number of acronyms and acronym calls in your document. (Although a search&replace might actually be quite easy...)

- Another possibility might be to use the `textcase` package which redefines `\MakeUppercase` so that we can tell LaTeX not to uppercase certain parts:

  ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{acro}
   \usepackage[overload]{textcase}

   \DeclareAcronym{sdn}{
     short = SDN ,
     long  = some dummy nonsense
   }

   \pagestyle{headings}

   \begin{document}

   \section{Moving Forward to Distributed \protect\NoCaseChange{\acs*{sdn}} Management}

   \end{document}
  ```
- As a third option which does not depend on the way the heading style is defined `acro` introduced the option `case-sensitive` earlier this year (with the release of v2.11 2020/01/11) in order to deal with this kind of problems. Assuming you don't have two different acronyms, one using `sdn` as ID and the other using `SDN` you can tell `acro` to treat both as the same:

  ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{acro}

   \acsetup{case-sensitive=false}

   \DeclareAcronym{sdn}{
     short = SDN ,
     long  = some dummy nonsense
   }

   \pagestyle{headings}

   \begin{document}

   \section{Moving Forward to Distributed \acs*{sdn} Management}

   \end{document}
  ```

The last two examples both give

[image]